# Change Username in Less than 30 Days

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My ex-girlfriend, who knows my password on Minecraft, changed my username to an inappropriate name. I could be banned on servers with this name; so how do I change it without having to wait for the 30-day wait time set by Mojang?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, you just have to wait. No way around it. If you want, you can try to contact [Mojang](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/emails/new), but don't get your hopes up.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

You have to wait for 30 days (if you think that it'll get you banned, don't play minecraft), or try contacting Mojang support to report your ex, and get your name reversed.

Comment: And what will reporting her do? There's nothing to be done with that except change his password so she can't login

Comment: @Alex one is like refund, one is like fraudulent charge. Stating that the username wasn't changed by asker might help mojang revert it.

Comment: Ok doubt that will work though. Just saying.